# Нужна здесь запятая или

Tags: пунктуация

ВЦИОМ знает, в чём счастье. Необходима ли запятая?

Answer (score 3):

> *ВЦИОМ знает, в чём счастье.* Необходима ли запятая?

.

Запятая нужна. См. [**у Розенталя:**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

> **§107.** Запятая между главным и придаточным предложениями
>
> <…>
>
> Запятой отделяются также неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные
>   предложения, например:
>
> *Он не понял, **в чем** дело.*

Answer (score 2):

ВЦИОМ знает, в чём счастье.  Запятая ставится.

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, В ЧЁМ ― союзное слово.

Придаточное предложение неполное (нет сказуемого).